# Inheriting a dynamic variable to inner class

Tags: python, websocket, binary-search-tree, inner-classes

Here's the background, to give you an idea of what I'm working with:

The code I'm working with starts with `WebsocketClient()` class as an outer class inherited by calling it as an object in the main class (unless I'm misunderstanding how that works). Then it uses the `on_message()` method to do certain things and update a global variable (a Red-Black binary tree) based on the message from the websocket server. (Keys for the global variable that get added from the websocket messages are usually random, and change/get updated multiple times per second.)

The main class has an inner class that reads the RBTree and displays info from it.

All this works fine, it's someone else's code (all open source). But when I add a method to the main class to read the RBTree and output different info from it, the RBTree seems to stop getting updated.

```
class MainClass(WebsocketClient):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()
        self._glbtree = RBTree()
    def on_message(self, message):
        #
        # stuff to update _glbtree
        #
        self.new_method()
    def new_method(self):
        print(self._glbtree.min_key())
    class InnerClass(MainClass):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainClass, self).__init__()
        def on_message(self, message):
            super(MainClass, self).on_message(message)
            print(self._glbtree.max_key())
    iclass = InnerClass()
    iclass.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(10)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        iclass.close()
```

The inner class runs and prints the most updated value for `.max_key()`, but when I uncomment `new_method(self)` and comment out the whole inner class and the last seven lines, it loads up the `_glbtree` once and updates the keys it has, but then doesn't get new keys or remove old keys once my `new_method()` starts running. So the more it runs, the older the results of `.min_key()` are (as in, there are most likely other keys that should be getting added or removed from `_glbtree` that should be showing up, but aren't.)

Note: There are a lot of other things (calculations, etc.) happening, but the code above is hopefully enough to give you an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Check to see if `.min_key()` is altering anything. That would be my first order of troubleshooting.

Comment: `.min_key()` is a built-in method in the `RBTree()` class, all it should be doing is returning the key with the lowest value.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees/

Comment: What is `iclass.start()`? It looks... suspiciously undefined. Line 19 in your example.

Comment: I'm not sure. I trimmed/modified most of the code for privacy, but that part (last 7 lines) is almost exactly what's in the opensource code.

Comment: Reading into it more, the `.start()` is part of the `WebsocketClient` class that they wrote (built using the `websocket-client` module that's on pypi). It basically calls the `_connect()` and `_listen()` methods to connect to the websocket server.

Comment: And why are the max_key print and the min_key print in different areas? Try putting them together.

Comment: I'm trying to make this work as simply as possible (which means trying to cut out the `InnerClass()` if possible) to improve performance. Milliseconds will be important.

Comment: What happens if you move it?

Comment: i move my `new_method()` to the `InnerClass()` class and move the method call to the `InnerClass().on_message()`, and it reacts the same way. if anything it's even more delayed and out of date than it was originally.

Comment: Did you add the print max_key?

Comment: the `.max_key()` is a simplification of what's already in the code (i didn't add it). ... or did you mean "did i run them at the same time?"

Comment: No, if it's already there, then it works. Try replacing the max_key call with a min_key call in the last known stable build.

Comment: Those two `print` lines are a representation of my code (`max_key()`) and the original/opensource code (`min_key()`). But I did try to implement the two pieces of code together, and got the same result as before. The last "stable" build is in pypi, and doesn't work (throws an error that has since been fixed, but not applied to pypi). I pulled their master from github and didn't get that error, but still have this problem that i created this question for.

Comment: no, you said `All this works fine, it's someone else's code (all open source). But when I add a method to the main class to read the RBTree and output different info from it, the RBTree seems to stop getting updated.`. So what happens if you keep the method out (Use the source that 'works fine') but where the `max_key()` call is, replace it with a `min_key()` call.